# Display the selected value of checkbox in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two checkboxes and a div in the body and I would like to display the selected value of data-valuetwo inside the div, "contents".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chkbx').click(function() {
        var selected = "";
        $('.chkbx:checked').each(function() {
            selected += $('.chkbx').attr('data-valuetwo') + ',';
        });
        selected = selected.substring(0, selected.length - 1);
        $('.selecteditems').val(selected);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Mike" id="customCheck1" name="choice[]">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Mike</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Jason" id="customCheck2" name="choice[]">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Jason</label>
</div>

<div class="contents">
    <h3>Options Selected: </h3>
    <textarea id="selecteditems">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are calling the class with $('.selecteditems').val(selected). Try changing it to $('#selecteditems').val(selected); since it's an id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

1) You have to use `this` keyword to target the current check box and

2) You are using class symbol (`.`) instead of id (`#`);

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chkbx').click(function() {
        var selected = "";
        $('.chkbx:checked').each(function() {
            selected += $(this).attr('data-valuetwo') + ',';
        });
        selected = selected.substring(0, selected.length - 1);
        $('#selecteditems').val(selected);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Mike" id="customCheck1" name="choice[]">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Mike</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Jason" id="customCheck2" name="choice[]">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Jason</label>
</div>

<div class="contents">
    <h3>Options Selected: </h3>
    <textarea id="selecteditems">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Though I prefer using `map()`, `get()` and `join()` which does not require `substring()` and lot more cleaner:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chkbx').click(function() {
        var selected = $('.chkbx:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-valuetwo');
        }).get().join(',');
        $('#selecteditems').val(selected);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Mike" id="customCheck1" name="choice[]">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Mike</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Jason" id="customCheck2" name="choice[]">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Jason</label>
</div>

<div class="contents">
    <h3>Options Selected: </h3>
    <textarea id="selecteditems">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Solution with DIV element, `<br>` and `html()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chkbx').click(function() {
        var selected = $('.chkbx:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-valuetwo');
        }).get().join('<br>');
        $('#selecteditems').html(selected);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Mike" id="customCheck1" name="choice[]">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Mike</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Jason" id="customCheck2" name="choice[]">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Jason</label>
</div>

<div class="contents">
    <h3>Options Selected: </h3>
    <div id="selecteditems">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i want to display in a div instead of textarea? I thought the codes would be identical if I change it..

Comment: @MinUD, in that case you have to simply use the `text()` property instead of `val()`:)

Comment: @Mamum thank you, last question, what if I would like to add a line break instead of a comma?

Comment: @MinUD, if you want them in separate line use `'\n'` like `$(this).attr('data-valuetwo') + '\n'` Or `.join('\n')`..... thanks:)

Comment: \n isn't working for me, it just adds a whitespace between selection

Comment: @MinUD, there is no reason that the change will not work......updated the first solution. Please check......

Comment: @Mamum oh sry, I works on textarea, but I was trying it on a div.

Comment: @MinUD, for div element, try with `<br>` and `html()`. I have added another answer with div element, please check that:)

Answer (score 1):

You have done 2 mistakes here.

1. Your `selecteditems` is a id not class.
2. You need to use `this` instead of class `$(this).attr('data-valuetwo')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.chkbx').click(function() {
            var selected = "";
            $('.chkbx:checked').each(function() {
                selected += $(this).attr('data-valuetwo') + ',';
            });
            selected = selected.substring(0, selected.length - 1);
            $('#selecteditems').val(selected);
            $('#divId').html(selected);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Mike" id="customCheck1" name="choice[]">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Mike</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Jason" id="customCheck2" name="choice[]">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Jason</label>
</div>

<div class="contents">
    <h3>Options Selected: </h3>
    <textarea id="selecteditems">
    </textarea>
</div>

<div id="divId"></div>
```

Comment: what if i want to display in a div instead of textarea? I thought the codes would be identical if I change it..

Comment: `$('#divId').html(selected);` this will update in div. updated in my code also

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the click event, use the `on('change')` event. Get the value of data-valuetwo of checkbox inside the event handler, using `this`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected = "";
    $('.chkbx').on('change', function() {
        selected += $(this).attr('data-valuetwo') + ',';
        selected = selected.substring(0, selected.length - 1);
        $('#selecteditems').val(selected);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prop` to check if the checkbox is checked or not. Then concat the value with a variable and use `val` to show in the `textarea`. On uncheck you can use string replace to remove the value of the check box and update the textarea

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let textAreaVal = '';
  $('.chkbx').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      textAreaVal += ' ' + $(this).data('valuetwo');
    } else {
      let data = $(this).data('valuetwo')
      textAreaVal = textAreaVal.replace(new RegExp(data, "g"), "");
    }
    $('#selecteditems').val(textAreaVal.trim())
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Mike" id="customCheck1" name="choice[]">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Mike</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chkbx" value="654321" data-valuetwo="Jason" id="customCheck2" name="choice[]">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Jason</label>
</div>

<div class="contents">
  <h3>Options Selected: </h3>
  <textarea id="selecteditems">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If You initialise the **selected** variable after an event, whenever you fire the button/checkbox it will will be re initialized and the value which it stores will be lost. Change your code to the following tested code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var selected = "";
                $('.chkbx').change(function () {
                    selected += $(this).attr('data-valuetwo') + ',';
                    selected = selected.substring(0, selected.length - 1);
                    $('#selecteditems').val(selected);
                });
            });
```