# How to enable and disable checkbox?

Tags: jquery

How to disable `teeth_input_3` when `teeth_input_4` is checked.

Enable it when `teeth_input_4` is unchecked again
one of three images `(img1,img4,img5)` is shown only

Hope to find help to solve this problem

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("teeth_input_2");
  var text = document.getElementById("img3");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    img3.style.display = "block";
    img2.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    img3.style.display = "none";
    img2.style.display = "block";
  }
}
function myFunction2() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("teeth_input_3");
  var text = document.getElementById("img4");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    img4.style.display = "block";
    img1.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    img4.style.display = "none";
    img1.style.display = "block";
  }
}
function myFunction3() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("teeth_input_4");
  var text = document.getElementById("img5");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    img5.style.display = "block";
    img4.style.display = "none";
    img1.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    img5.style.display = "none";
    myFunction2()

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="img1" src="a.jpg" alt="present left 8" style="display: block;">
  <img id="img4" src="c.jpg" alt="Endo" style="display: none;">
  <img id="img5" src="c.jpg" alt="Implant" style="display: none;">
  <img id="img2" src="b.jpg" alt="Not Caries" style="display: block;">
  <img id="img3" src="c.jpg" alt="Caries" style="display: none;">

</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="teeth_input_1" checked>Present
<br /><input type="checkbox" id="teeth_input_2" onclick="myFunction()">Caries
<br /><input type="checkbox" id="teeth_input_3" onclick="myFunction2()">Endo
<br /><input type="checkbox" id="teeth_input_4" onclick="myFunction3()">Implant
```

Comment: Disabled? How exactly? When A gets checked B is... 1. unchecked but can be checked again if the users wishes to do so. 2. unchecked and cannot be rechecked until A is unchecked. 3. still checked but user can't use it anymore until A is unchecked. 4.....???

Comment: refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56626637/9560041) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56626313/9560041) you can get an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got other event together, no need call function, can do like this.

```html
<input name="teeth_input" type="checkbox" id="teeth_input_1" checked>Present<br>
<input name="teeth_input" type="checkbox" id="teeth_input_2" >Caries<br>
<input name="teeth_input" type="checkbox" id="teeth_input_3" >Endo<br>
<input name="teeth_input" type="checkbox" id="teeth_input_4" >Implant
```

Put name for input, so that event can occur when other input be clicked.

```js
$('input[name="teeth_input"]:checkbox').change(function () {
   if ($("#teeth_input_2").is(':checked')) {
     $("#img2").hide();
     $("#img3").show();
   }
   else if ($("#teeth_input_2").is(':checked')) {
     $("#img2").hide();
     $("#img3").show();
   }
   if ($("#teeth_input_3").is(':checked')) {
     $("#img1").hide();
     $("#img4").show();
   }
   else if (!$("#teeth_input_3").is(':checked')) {
     $("#img4").hide();
     $("#img1").show();
   }
   if ($("#teeth_input_4").is(':checked')) { 
     $("#teeth_input_3 ").attr("disabled", true);
     $("#img5").hide();
   } 
   else if (!$("#teeth_input_4").is(':checked')) {
     $("#teeth_input_3").attr("disabled", false);
     $("#img1").show();
     $("#img4").show();
     $("#img5").show();
   }
});
```

**OR**

```js
$("#teeth_input_4").change( function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) { $("#teeth_input_3").attr("disabled", true); } 
  else {
       $("#teeth_input_3").attr("disabled", false);
       $("#img1").show();
       $("#img4").show();
       $("#img5").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: you should put it in  some fiddle like https://jsfiddle.net/ to test it

Comment: I do not know what you cannot.
I change some in https://jsfiddle.net/35t9dkm6, you can reference.
But @fionka, be clear disabled checkbox 3 is useless if checkbox already checked.
Why you want to disable it, you may need to unchecked so